# Unit test coverage with grunt-karma-sonar

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sonarqube, karma-runner

I'm trying to get unit tests and test coverage working with Grunt, Karma, and Sonar. I'm working through [this tutorial](http://ahexamples.blogspot.com/2014/03/example-of-jasmine-karma-sonar-grunt.html).

Here are my dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bower": "~1.3.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-karma-sonar": "~0.1.3",
    "istanbul": "~0.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.3.4",
    "karma": "~0.12.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.12",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-junit-sonarqube-reporter": "0.0.1",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.4.0",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.19",
}
```

Here's my gruntfile:

```
//require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var $srcFiles = 'taf_table_view/js/*.js';
    var $testFiles = 'test/*.js';
    var $outputDir = 'test_results'
    var $junitResults = $outputDir + '/junit-test-results.xml';
    var $jasmineSpecRunner = $outputDir + '/_SpecRunner.html';
    var $coverageOutputDir = $outputDir + '/coverage';

    grunt.initConfig({
         pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'), // Read project settings from package.json
         // Jasmine test
         jasmine: {
             pivotal: {
                 src: [
                     // load dependencies first and make sure angular
                     'taf_table_view/lib/angular/angular.js',
                     'taf_table_view/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js',
                     'taf_table_view/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
                     'taf_table_view/lib/angular-loader/angular-loader.js',
                     'taf_table_view/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',

                     // load taf_table_view and test scripts
                     'taf_table_view/js/*.js',
                     'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js',
                     'test/*.js'
                 ],
                 options: {
                     specs: $testFiles,
                     outfile: $jasmineSpecRunner,
                     keepRunner: 'true' // keep SpecRunner/outfile file
                 }
             }
         },
         karma: { // documentation: https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma
             plugins : [
                 'karma-chrome-launcher',
                 'karma-firefox-launcher',
                 'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
                 'karma-jasmine',

                 // needed for sonar plugin
                 'karma-junit-reporter',
                 'karma-coverage'
             ],
             continuous: {
                 singleRun: 'true',
                 browsers: [ 'PhantomJS' ]  // PhantomJS
             },
             options: {
                 configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
             },
             unit: {
                 singleRun: true,
                 reporters: ['junit', 'coverage']
             }
             //continuous: {
             //    background: true
             //}
         },
         karma_sonar: {  // documentation: https://github.com/mdasberg/grunt-karma-sonar
             //  http://ahexamples.blogspot.com/2014/03/example-of-jasmine-karma-sonar-grunt.html
             options: {
                 defaultOutputDir: '/sonar/',
                 instance: {
                    //  http://localhost:9000  // http://10.207.120.229:9000
                     hostUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
                     //  jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar // jdbc:postgresql://10.207.120.229:5432/sonar
                     jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar',
                     login: 'sonar',
                     // sonar
                     password: 'sonar1dev'
                 }
             },
             update_sonar: {
                 project: {  // Project information shown in sonar
                     key: 'taf-table-view',
                     name: 'TAF Table View',
                     version: '0.0.1'
                 }

                 // sources set at runtime
             }
         }
     });

    grunt.registerTask('set-karma-sonar-sources-property', function() {
        var $done = this.async();
        var $phantomjs = require('karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs');
        var $spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var $phantomUserAgent = $spawn($phantomjs.path,
                                       // phantomjs script to print user agent string
                                       [ 'lib/phantomjs-useragent.js' ]
        );

        /*
         * Construct coverage LCOV file path from PHantomJs'
         * user agent string, then use it to set karmaSonar's
         * sources property.
         */
        $phantomUserAgent.stdout.on('data', function(msg) {
            var $useragent = require('karma/node_modules/useragent');
            var $agent = $useragent.parse(msg);
            // An example of dirName is 'PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)'
            var $dirName = $agent.toAgent() + ' (' + $agent.os + ')';
            var $coverageResults = $coverageOutputDir + '/' + $dirName + '/lcov.info';
            var $sonarSources = makeSonarSourceDirs($srcFiles, $coverageResults);
            var $karmaSonarConfig = 'karmaSonar';
            var $ksConfig = grunt.config($karmaSonarConfig);

            grunt.log.writeln('coverage LCOV file: ' + $coverageResults);
            $ksConfig['your_target']['sources'] = $sonarSources;
            grunt.config($karmaSonarConfig, $ksConfig);

        });

        $phantomUserAgent.on('close', function(exitCode) {
            $done();
        });


        /*
         * Create sonar source object for each directory of source file pattern.
         */
        function makeSonarSourceDirs($filesPattern, $coverageResults) {
            var $path = require('path');
            var $dirs = [];

            grunt.file.expand(
                {
                    filter: function($filePath) {
                        $dirs.push({
                                       path: $path.dirname($filePath),
                                       prefix: '.', // path prefix in lcov.info
                                       coverageReport: $coverageResults,
                                       testReport: $junitResults
                                   });
                    }
                },
                $filesPattern
            );

            return $dirs;
        }
    });

    // Tell Grunt we plan to use these plug-ins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma-sonar');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('load-grunt-tasks');

    grunt.registerTask('test', [ 'jasmine', 'karma:continuous' ]);
    grunt.registerTask('sonar-only', [ 'set-karma-sonar-sources-property', 'karma_sonar:update_sonar' ]);
    grunt.registerTask('sonar', [ 'test', 'sonar-only' ]);
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'test');
```

Here's the error I get when I run grunt sonar:

> Running "set-karma-sonar-sources-property" task
>   Warning: Cannot find module 'karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs' Use --force to continue.

Comment: Do you have karma-phantomjs-launcher installed?

Comment: Try to install phantomjs as global dependency `npm install phantomjs -g`

Comment: Yeah I have it in my devDependencies and declared in the plugins of Karma section of my Gruntfile.

Comment: I installed phantomjs globally and still got the same error. I then installed karma-phantomjs-launcher and still am getting the same error. Thanks for the suggestion @Ruben Nagoga

Comment: Could you post your karma configuration file? `karma-phantomjs-launcher` is known to have quite a few issues that you can see on Github.  It is possible that there is a compatibility issue between Grunt and Karma?  It's hard to say.  Maybe you can exclude the karma plugins section from your Grunt file and just include them in the karma configuration file.